# Improving work relationship with my advisor

Tags: advisor, research-undergraduate, academic-life

I'm new to the research scene. I asked my advisor questions about the suggestions he gave in a couple of meetings. From then on, he insulted me a few times whenever he has to provide feedback on my work in our project meetings and he responds in an aggressive way when I ask him doubts as well. One time, he questioned my degree and skills for the feedback of 'bolding a boundary in a visual illustration' and we had a poster deadline then in a few days. I'm not sure if he did this in spite, but he asked us to send him a final draft, which we did before the poster deadline. And he did not provide us any feedback or response on the draft or us submitting the deadline.
Earlier it was fine, he responded politely more or less. How do I fix this now?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/118465/75368, though the linked question is more focused on doctoral research.